# how should we I use a modelEvaluator of JPMML evaluator in java multithreaded code?

Tags: java, multithreading, pmml

I am using JPMML Evaluator library and PMML instance is common for all evaluator will it block the evaluator and create locking. while processing in multithreaded fashion.

```
//single threaded

PMML pmml = <new pmml>

//multithreaded
ModelEvaluator<MiningModel> someModelEvaluatorThread = new MiningModelEvaluator(genderPmml);
```

will it work or hit on performance. I am not creating pmml thread specific because I don't want to parse the same file again and again.

Answer (score 2):

The README.md file of the JPMML-Evaluator library says:

> Model evaluator classes follow functional programming principles and are completely thread safe.

Doesn't matter if you share the same model evaluator instance between all threads, or create a separate model evaluator instance for each thread - they will all get along very nicely. The mutable state is encapsulated in `org.jpmml.evaluator.EvaluationContext` object instance, which is "private" to each evaluation request.

Also, the JPMML-Evaluator library doesn't contain any `synchronized` code blocks, and doesn't use any locking mechanisms. The throughput of your application should increase linearly as you start more threads.

Comment: thanks buddy I found the issue it was the issue of contention due to JPMML used parseDouble from java library which is synchronized and causing thread blocking which is fixed in java 8

Comment: Very interesting observation! For documentation purposes, here's the detailed description of this JDK issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7032154